# How do I return in a function two different lists? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

How do I return two different lists in a function I made?

```py
def eolist(num1):
    li_1 = []
    li_2 = []
    for i in range(1, num1+1):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            li_2.append(i)
        else:
            li_1.append(i)
    return li_1, li_2
```

Comment: Just like you did. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

or you can use dict like this

```
class test():
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []

    ...

    return dict(one=list_1, two=list_2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the list in a structure so that you have only one return parameter. (List, tuple, ...)  Here i do it in a tuple:

```
def eolist(num1):
    li_1 = []
    li_2 = []
    for i in range(1, num1+1):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            li_2.append(i)
        else:
            li_1.append(i)
    return (li_1, li_2 )
    # return li_1, li_2  (is the same for tuple)
```

After the call you can assign it again in two lists.

```
li_1, li_2 = eolist(10)
print(li_1)
print(li_2)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. `return (li_1, li_2)` works exactly the same way as OP's `return li_1, li_2` does. The parenthesis are not needed

Comment: Okay you mean it is an answer but it is not necessary? Okay.. but maybe he didnt know how to assign the lists after the call?